# Why isn't AngularJS rendering?

Tags: angularjs

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in this example? The braces are output instead of rendered AngularJS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <input type="text" ng-model="mydata" />
  <br/> {{mydata}}
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6R4g78v32lhNdRWZ1qHE?p=preview

Comment: Please include the contents of `script.js`.

Comment: You don't have a controller that defines myData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Angular 1 syntax, but you have Angular 2 included as a script tag.

Once the right version is included, your code works as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/2CiGn5mUekycyRaJPnVZ?p=preview

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If the syntax was fixed, what would be rendered?

Comment: Updated answer with a fixed version of their Plunker.